# Using logical OR in a Bash shell if statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, logical-operators

I don't understand why this `if` statement is giving an error saying:

> Using too many arguments

```
if [ $file == 'Metro[0-9]*' ] -o [ $file == 'Store[0-9]*' ]

     echo "$file"
```

I literally used every combination of parentheses thinking that there might be a mistake but nothing changed. The interesting thing is, condition works if I just use one of the conditions and erase the other. So I assume there is something wrong with using the `-o` or parentheses...

Comment: aren't you missing the `then` and `fi` statements?

Comment: can you elaborate little more what you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no shell operator `-o`, you seem to be looking for

```
if [[ $file == 'Metro'[0-9]* || $file == 'Store'[0-9]* ]]; then
   echo "$file"
fi
```

which is of course somewhat more succinctly and portably written

```
case $file in 'Metro'[0-9]* | 'Store'[0-9]*) echo "$file";; esac
```

Notice the multiple changes in quoting: wildcards mustn't be inside quotes if you want them expanded, and the file name should generally be inside double quotes (though it's not necessary after `[[` or `case`).

Notice also the change to `[[` which is not a POSIX `sh` command -- the first alternative above is specific to Bash / Ksh / other "modern" extended shells.  The POSIX `[` (aka `test`) doesn't have a simple way to check if a file matches an arbitrary wildcard expression. Indicentally, Bash also supports `if [ condition1 -o condition2 ]` but that isn't portable, either, so in a way the worst of two worlds.

Answer (score 1):

- Your `if` condition is missing `then` and `fi`.
- The `-o` operator does not exist, but you can use `||` to represent OR.
- Since you're using Bash, you can use the `=~` operator to compare a string against a regex.

So you can write your condition like this:

```
if [[ "$file" =~ (Metro|Store)[0-9]* ]] ; then
     echo "$file"
fi
```